# How do i input values of matrix into a specific column in a matrix i have already generated in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, modeling, population

I am doing a matrix modeling project for a biology class using MATLAB. I set the matrix to all zeroes in a 3 by 100 matrix. ie. Pop_size = zeros(3, 100). How do i then input values to the first column of the matrix. I tried Pop_size(1:3, 1) = (100, 100, 100). It told me i have an error and that it is possibly due to unbalanced brackets. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `Pop_size(1:3, 1) = (100, 100, 100)` should be `Pop_size(1:3, 1) = [100, 100, 100]`

Comment: the basics of MATLAB matrix indexing http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your matrix using brackets instead of parenthesis:

```
Pop_size(1:3, 1) = [100 100 100]
```